# How to stream S3 object directly from Java web server to browser

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I have tried so far is

```
S3Object object = s3Object.getObject(new getObjectRequest(bucketName,FileName));
InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = object.getObjectContent();
// Setting Headers.
return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource,headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

But this code is not streaming date to browser. I has first downloaded to server and then sent back to browser but requirement is to directly stream to browser without downloading at server.

Any pseudocode or link will help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `getObject()`, create a signed GET request and send a 302 redirect to the client. The browser will then retrieve the object directly from Amazon. In case you aren't already using it, the jets3t library makes dealing with S3 signatures much simpler.

Comment: On redirect I am getting response "Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified"

Comment: @San Post code and say where you're getting that message.

Comment: It is working fine now. The requested URL had another authToken because of which we were getting exception.